# convert setHeader to use https

Tags: php

Can anyone please help in converting this bit of code to send the header response via HTTPS in php

```
protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
    $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
    $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
    $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
    $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
    $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
    $response->setBody($content);
    $response->sendResponse();
    die;
}
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with HTTPS. You need to configure the server. The PHP code does not need to be altered at all.

Comment: install ssl certificate, configure Apache, use https.

Comment: I have installed SSL & configured it. But the following code does work when I try to use https for my admin panel. It only works if i use the admin panel in http mode.